# tidyr::spread() gives an Error

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

**SOLVED**

Please, help to figure out what might be wrong with the following example.

```
library(tidyverse)

(freq <- structure(list(Year_of_diagnosis = c(2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 
                                             2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 
                                             2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L), 
                       Sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
                       n = c(70L, 180L, 70L, 170L, 70L, 180L, 60L, 220L, 80L, 190L, 80L, 230L, 60L, 210L, 70L, 230L,
                             70L, 220L, 70L, 220L, 80L, 230L)), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Year", "Sex", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -22L)))
```

an issue is here:

```
tidyr::spread(freq, key = Sex, value = n)
```

it gives the following error:

**Error in matrixToDataFrame(x) : 
  object '_tibble_matrixToDataFrame' not found**

I updated packages not so far:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.2     purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.7.0     tibble_1.3.4    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12     cellranger_1.1.0 compiler_3.4.1   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1        forcats_0.2.0    tools_3.4.1      lubridate_1.6.0 
 [9] jsonlite_1.5     nlme_3.1-131     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.2      psych_1.7.5      parallel_3.4.1  
[17] haven_1.1.0      bindrcpp_0.2     xml2_1.1.1       stringr_1.2.0    httr_1.3.1       hms_0.3          tidyselect_0.2.0 grid_3.4.1      
[25] glue_1.1.1       R6_2.2.2         readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-69   modelr_0.1.1     reshape2_1.4.2   magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0    
[33] rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5     colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.5    lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.2
```

eipi10's Session Info:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.2 tidyr_0.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.1.1 compiler_3.4.1   assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         magrittr_1.5     tools_3.4.1      bindrcpp_0.2     glue_1.1.1       tibble_1.3.4    
[10] yaml_2.1.14      Rcpp_0.12.12     pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.2      bindr_0.1        purrr_0.2.3
```

**Update**: [credit to @aosmith]
reinstalling `tidyverse` in a fresh session helped.

Comment: I ran your code with no problems on R version 3.2.4, tidy version 0.4.1, dplyr version 0.4.3.

Comment: thanks, I will probably report the bug to `tidyr` team that 'spread()` function has an issue with newer R version

Comment: No problem when running your code with R 3.4.1, dplyr 0.7.2 and tidyr 0.7.0.

Comment: @eipi Could you, please, show your full `sessionInfo()` for this R session example?

Comment: I've added my Session Info as an edit to your question. Feel free to delete it once you've had a chance to look it over.

Comment: Try reinstalling in a fresh session as recommended in [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/349).